# Can someone help me to evaluate or at least to approximate the following sum.

Tags: number-theory

Can someone help me to evaluate the following sum. It appeared while calculating the number of elements of intersections of some sets:
$$\sum_{d|n} \frac{d}{\phi(d)^2}.$$

Comment: It looks to be a multiplicative function, and the result for prime powers is somewhat tractable.  Have you already looked at it to that extent?

Comment: To extend on hardmath's finding I got indeed $f(p)=\frac{p^2-p+1}{(p-1)^2}$ (the 'distribution' obtained is very regular with a mean value of $\approx 3.39063$)

Answer (score 8):

Since $\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)^2}$ is a multiplicative function, we know that
$$
\varphi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{d}{\phi(d)^2}\tag{1}
$$
is also multiplicative. On the power of a prime, $p^j$ and $j>0$, $\phi(p^j)=p^j\frac{p-1}{p}$, so
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi(p^k)
&=1+\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{p^2}{p^j(p-1)^2}\\
&=1+\frac{p}{(p-1)^2}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{p^j}\\
&=1+\frac{p^k-1}{p^{k-2}(p-1)^3}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $n$ whose prime factorization is
$$
n=\prod_jp_j^{k_j}\tag{3}
$$
we have
$$
\varphi(n)=\prod_j\left(1+\frac{p_j^{k_j}-1}{p_j^{k_j-2}(p_j-1)^3}\right)\tag{4}
$$
**Estimation:**

Note that for $k>0$,
$$
1+\frac1p\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^2\le1+\frac{p^k-1}{p^{k-2}(p-1)^3}\lt1+\frac1p\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^3\tag{5}
$$
For larger primes, $(5)$ might help to approximate the term in $(4)$.

Comment: An equivalent for $f(p^k)$ is $1 + \frac{p^2}{(p-1)^3} (1 - p^{-k})$, which makes it clearer what the limit is as $k$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @hardmath: thanks! I was just writing up an estimate along those lines.